# Show truncated preview and full message

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form where I select a message from a dropdown field and then show the message in a textarea box beside it.  I use jquery to pull the value of the dropbox and put it as the value of the textarea, like so:

```
$("#id_maturity_letter").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("#message_text").val($("option:selected", this).text());
    $.getJSON('', {id:id}, function(json) {

    });

});
```

My only issue is that my message returns like so:

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return "%s" % self.body[0:20]
```

Reason being so that the message in the dropdown doesn't span the entire page and then some.  Now is it possible to show a truncated message in the dropdown but a full message in the "preview" textbox?  Using jquery/django of course.

I am having trouble trying to figure this one out.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two dropdown lists: one with truncated texts and one (hidden) with full text

or build a js array with id -> full description